Error configuración DateRangePickers
Me esta ocurriendo una cosa muy rara con la biblioteca DateRangePickers.
Con el apartado de configuracion que te deja crear un vistazo previo del calendario he visto opciones para añadir a los que ya tengo (DateRangePickers Config)
La cuestion es que en los dos calendarios que uso tienen ambos la misma configuracion
HTML
<!-- Fecha inicio -->
<div class="col-xxl-4 date-field" style="display: none;">
    <label class="form-label"><?= lang('General.startDate') ?></label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-solid" name="start_date" placeholder="Pick start date" id="kt_start_date" />
</div>
<!-- Fecha Fin -->
<div class="col-xxl-4 date-field" style="display: none;">
    <label class="form-label"><?= lang('General.endDate') ?></label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-solid" name="end_date" placeholder="Pick end date" id="kt_end_date" />
</div>

Script
var end = moment();
var start = moment();

//Configuración de localización para los datepickers
var localeData = {
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    applyLabel: "<?= lang('General.send') ?>",
    cancelLabel: "<?= lang('General.close') ?>",
    firstDay: moment.localeData()._week.dow
};

// Inicializar el date picker de la fecha de inicio
$("#kt_start_date").daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    startDate: start,
    autoApply: true,
    locale: localeData,
    showDropdowns: true,
    drops: 'up'
});

// Inicializar el date picker de la fecha de fin
$("#kt_end_date").daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    startDate: end,
    autoApply: true,
    locale: localeData,
    showDropdowns: true,
    drops: 'up'
});

ambos tiene  las opciones configuradas para que permita el cambio de mes y año (showDropdowns: true) y que se muestre encima del input (drops: 'up').
Pues el calendario de la fecha final no toma en cuenta la opcion de cambio de mes y año, os adjunto capturas
Calendario Inicio

Calendario Fin

Como se aprecia el calendario de inicio tiene el selector de mes y año el de fecha final no teniendo la misma configuración, es algo que me esta extrañando mucho.
!Muchísimas gracias!

Prueba configurando minDate y maxDate o puedes probar también pasando el objeto maxSpan, que sería algo así: maxSpan: {"days": 90}.  https://www.daterangepicker.com/#options

@og.lopar711 he probado a meter minDate y maxDate y nada y tambien con el maxSpan tampoco aparece la opcion del cambio de año, voy a comprobar si esque se buggea si los dos tienen  la opcion de show dropdowns activa

@og.lopar711 buenos dias! después de este puente llego a la oficina y vuelvo a continuar en intentar solucionar el problema y mágicamente ahora ya tiene el cambio de mes año, sospecho de que pudiera ser por la cache del navegador ya que el equipo donde me pasaba esto no es mi equipo habitual. La verdad que no era normal que con la misma configuración uno fuera y otro no

Que tal amigo, que bueno que lo solucionaste! Para asegurarte de que no se utiliza la caché puedes desactivarla desde la consola del navegador (en chrome) en la pestaña network, ahi hay una opción llamada "disable cache". Saludos y felíz código

@og.lopar711 exacto!, en mi PC habitual de trabajo las desactive hace mucho tiempo, pero en el nuevo pues no caí, mil gracias!!
